# How to Open an Excel Workbook using reflection using c#

Tags: c#

How to Open an Excel Workbook using reflection without adding a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ?

I have tried:

```
Type mExcelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
            object    mExcelObj = Activator.CreateInstance(mExcelType);

Type tWorkbooksType;
                object tWorkbooks = null;

var tPropertyInfo = mExcelType.GetProperty("Workbooks");
                tWorkbooks = tPropertyInfo.GetValue(mExcelObj, null);
                var tPars = new object[15];
                tPars[0] = pFilePath;

                var w = tPropertyInfo.PropertyType.GetMethod("Open").Invoke(tWorkbooks, BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, tPars, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: and then.. What happened?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection to accomplish this? And is this ASP.NET context by any chance?

Comment: You didn't give us much information to work with. Right off the top of my head, though, I'm pretty sure you need to pass `Type.Missing` for the parameters you didn't fill in, `null` isn't the right value.

Comment: @Luaan you are right, I needed to pass Type.Missing for parameters. Thanks :)

Comment: Great :) I've added that as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pass `null` to the optional parameters when you don't want to supply them. Instead, you have to pass `Type.Missing`.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) tPars[i] = Type.Missing;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `dynamic` type. This provides late binding to your object.

```
Type excel_type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
dynamic excel_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(excel_type);
.
.
.
```

You need to be targeting .NET Framework 4.0 or newer.

Comment: You forgot to create the instance :)